# Trying to pull data from google places API

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

Trying to pull the data from Google Places API but can't get it work after reading the documentation. I must be missing something, anyone out there can help?

```
<script>

    var request = {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316), 
        radius: '500',
        types: ['store']
    };

    var service = new google.maps.places.PlaceService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

    function callback(results, status) {
        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            document.write(results[i] + '<br/>'); 
        }
    };      


    </script>
```

---

I got the error to go away by changing my code to this:

```
    var request = {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316), 
        radius: '500',
        types: ['store']
    };


    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
     if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){
    function callback(results, status) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            document.write(results[i] + 'test <br/>'); 
        }
        }
    };      


    </script>
```

However it is still not returning any data. Some one please help. Thanks!!!

Comment: so what does "can't get it to work"

Comment: Keep getting "undefined is not a function " as an error. Nothing is being returned. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are code examples for the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 - Places Library on the [Examples page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) of the documentation.

You can see a working example of the Place Library Nearby Search [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search).